How to transform real GDP in LCU to USD?
Let's suppose Suriname's constant GDP is SRD 15.1 billion in 2022. I'm not sure of the year's constant prices because the source does not specify it (https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.MKTP.KN?locations=SR).
How can I convert that value to USD? I'm not sure if just dividing 15.1 by the average exchange rate of 2022 is correct since that is the nominal exchange rate. Thank you.

No need for you to do any conversions. There are $US series (current/nominal and constant/real) available in the World Bank Databank (just search there for the other GDP indicators).
